# Issue passing $f3->set variables through reroute function

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am using the fat-free-framework to develop a web application and I am trying to make the application as professional as possible by providing helpful messages that display when actions have happened.

For example, when registering, if the two passwords entered do not match, the application will send the application back to the register route which displays the form along with a message which can be displayed in the view.

I am however having an issue displaying the message when the register form is shown again and I have a feeling its something to do with the reroute function that is causing the issue.

showRegister() function for /register where method type is GET:

```
public function showRegister($f3)
{
    $f3->clear('SESSION');

    $f3->set('title','Register');
    $f3->set('content','/pages/register.php');

    $f3->set('message',$f3->get('message'));
}
```

Register() function for /register where method type is POST:

```
public function register($f3)
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if($password != $password2)
    {
        $f3->set('message','The passwords you entered do not match. Please try again.');
        $f3->reroute('/register');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Awesome!";
    }
}
```

Line from the layout view that will echo out the message saved in $f3->set().

```
if(isset($message)) {echo $this->render(Base::instance()->get('message'));}
```

I have used the last line in the showRegister() function as an attempt to get around the problem but it has made no difference.

If anyone has a solution or work around that would be great.

Thank you,
Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. Either you cache the variable by setting 3rd parameter of `set()`, or you use a session, which I prefer.

```
$f3->set('SESSION.message', 'foo bar');
```

which is then accessable via `get()` or directly in the template via `{{@SESSION.message}}`

Comment: I've chosen to use a session for this but now I'm having an issue with the message rendering on the page. I now use: `$f3->set('SESSION.message','The passwords you entered do not match. Please try again.');
   $f3->reroute('/register');` and inside the layout file I have `{{@SESSION.message}}` just at the top of the page inside the body tag but the message doesn't update.

Comment: In the browser all I see is {{@SESSION.message}}, when the criteria of the if statement checking the two passwords is correct and the page redirects, the message doesn't get displayed where {{@SESSION.message}} is.

Comment: Looks like you're not using the template class.

Comment: instead of View::instance->render() use Template::instance->render();